# There must to be a way to use Xdebug

Tags: netbeans-7, xdebug

I have been trying for almost 3 years to use Xdebug. ONE time I got it to work on a linux system... Local only. Other than that, Windows, remote, hybrid, NOTHING! I am POSITIVE someone has made it work or else it wouldn't exist. Can someone PLEASE offer some advise to help me get this thing running?

This is my scenario.

Windows 7, Netbeans 7.4 beta
Code resides on linux box (crunchbang)
I have drives mappaed in windows so I access the codes from the linux machine

This is my php.ini

```
zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9-nts.dll
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.1.200 //linux box
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
output_buffering = off;
```

When I attempt to debug, I get perpetual nothingness... never connects...
There must be SOMETHING I can do/try to make this happen!

I have seen dozens of questions on here, usually with the same 2 or 3 answers and none of them have been helpful. Looking for ANY helpful advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it is simple not possible to debug PHP applications via NetBeans in Windows 7. After 3 years of trying, that is the only solution I can surmise.